# Is there a way to hook my Super Nintendo to my 2 year old Vizio TV?

Tags: technical-issues, snes

I bought my Vizio TV 2 years ago and I just got my Super Nintendo from my parents' house.  I tried hooking it up to both of the TVs I have and neither of them even recognized that I had it hooked up. The only 2 cords that my SNES has ever had are the power cord and the [RF switch](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/nes/hook_rfvcr.jsp), which has a coaxial output.  Is there any way I can get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to depend on what inputs the TV has.  Most TVs still have coaxial input (ie, the kind that screws on).  The TV must be on the right input and tuned to the right channel.  Typically this is "TV" or "Coax" input, and channel 3.  It may vary depending on your TV.  Sometimes pushing the "Channel Up" or "Channel Down" buttons on the remote will switch it to this input.

If that's not working, you can pick up a [composite cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PRKZ1M), which may help if it has a composite input.  Most TVs still do - it's an input with one "yellow" jack for video, and a "red/white" pair for audio.  (pic on [this page](http://www.cabletrain.com/cable-guide), go down to "composite") If you're wanting to get it going today, check with GameStop or wherever used games are sold in your area.  New game stores may also stock it, but call first.  I believe that the GameCube, the Nintendo 64, and the Super Nintendo all use the [same](http://techforums.nintendo.com/message/4101) [cables](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/26770893), so you might have better luck if you ask for a more modern revision of the hardware.

Comment: the tv still has the screw on and the cord has the option of channel 3 or 4 i tried both but still got nothing.

Comment: @Heidi, Note that you have to *tune the TV* to channel 3 or 4 as well as flipping the switch to the correct position.  From your comment, I'm not sure if you tried that or not.

Comment: Coaxial input needs to be set to `NTSC` for the Americas, and `PAL` for Europe.

Answer (score 0):

I have roughly 2 year old Vizio. I pressed the menu button and went to channels on the tv settings screen. I clicked on “Find Channels” and during the scan I cancelled the scan. Not sure if it was luck, but my NES was already turned on and it started playing on the screen as soon as I cancelled the scan.